# How much more is the value of the perimeter of the equilateral triangle compared to the bisector of the same triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

How much more is the value of the perimeter of the equilateral triangle compared to the bisector of the same triangle ?

How I did it:

probably easy but I don't get the answer, the perimeter of the equilateral triangle = $3x$, bisector = $\sqrt{3}x$
then dividing the perimeter by bisector length, i get $\sqrt{3}$, how should I do this?

correct answer is 2$\sqrt{3}$

[image]

Comment: The bisector length is not $\sqrt 3$. Please doublecheck.

Comment: yeah lol, I used 30 60 90  ratios like a robot